# numpy syntax for slicing with gaps and edge boundaries

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of a word corpus and I am trying to find a co-occurrence matrix with a window size as parameter so that every word from i-window_size to i+window_size apart from the word itself i has a co-count that is added. I am currently using two loops for it

```
words, num_words = distinct_words(array)
M = None
word2Ind = {}


M = np.zeros((num_words,num_words))
word2Ind = {word:words.index(word) for word in words}


for index,word in enumerate(array):
    for i in range(index-window_size,index):
         M[word2ind(array[index-i]),word2ind(array[index])] += 1

for index,word in enumerate(array):
    for i in range(index+1,index+window_size+1):
         M[word2ind(array[index+i]),word2ind(array[index])] += 1
```

The problem is also that I don't know how to handle edge cases seamlessly on the boundary as for i in range(0,window_size) and range(len(array),len(array)-window_size,-1) we won't have the entire range. Just wanted to know some efficient pointers to do this

Comment: where did you define `array`?

Comment: Sorry I corrected it corpus is the array. I downloaded it from the web

Comment: your code is full of undefined variables, where did you define `a`?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you're trying to do without some data or a picture or something. But any time you are trying to 'scan' over an array with some sort of window, you probably want convolution, eg with `scipy.signal.convolve2d` or (if you need more customizing) `scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter`. It will be way faster than looping.